# Using Eloquent to create a new conversation

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I am writing a conversation system for my application using the `Laravel` framework. I can currently have a conversation in the application if I've hardcoded the conversation in the database.

Now, I can't quite figure out how to actually create a new `Conversation` in `Laravel`. When creating a new `Conversation`, I need to add a new entry to the `conversations` table and the users and `conversation_id` to `conversation_user`.

How can I do this? Below is what I currently have.

I have 3 database tables

conversations:

`id |`

conversation_user:

`id | conversation_id | user_id`

messages:

`id | message | user_id | conversation_id | created_at`

I have 2 models

Conversation

```
class Conversation extends Eloquent {
    public $table = 'conversations';

    public $includes = array('User', 'Message');

    public function user() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('User');
    }

    public function message() {
        return $this->hasMany('message');
    }
}
```

Message

```
class Message extends Eloquent {
    public $table = 'messages';

    public $includes = array('User', 'Conversation');

    protected $fillable = array('message', 'user_id', 'conversation_id');

    public function user() {
        return $this->belongsTo('User');
    }

    public function conversation() {
        return $this->belongsTo('Conversation');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked out

```
$conversation = Conversation::create(array());
$conversation->user()->attach(Sentry::getUser()->id);
$conversation->user()->attach($id);
$conversation->save();
```